# How do I resolve the error resulting from this Simple Linear Regression in Python and Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, neural-network, linear-regression

So, I'm trying to make a simple neural network for linear regression using only python and numpy.
I have solved most of the original problems and it works well except that the network's error only increases.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class Regression:
    def __init__(self,size):
        self.W = np.random.random(size)
        self.b = np.random.random(size[1])
    def test(self,X):
        return X@self.W + self.b
    def train(self,X,Y, epochs = 50, lr = 0.2):
        self.error_list = []
        for i in range(epochs):
            pred  = self.test(X)
            error = (Y - pred)**2
            error_pred = -2*(Y - pred)
            
            pred_W = X.T
            pred_b = np.ones_like(self.b)
            
            error_W = pred_W @ error_pred
            error_b = np.sum(error_pred * pred_b, 0)

            self.W -= error_W * lr
            self.b -= error_b * lr

            self.error_list.append(np.mean(error))

        plt.plot(self.error_list)
        plt.title("Training Loss")
        plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nn = Regression([2,1])
    X = np.array([[0,0],
                  [0,1],
                  [1,0],
                  [1,1]])
    Y = np.sum(X,1).reshape(-1,1)
    nn.train(X,Y,100)
    print(nn.test([[1,2],
                   [2,3]]))
```

This is the final output:

```
[[5.23598775e+18]
 [7.47065723e+18]]
```

See plot here:
[Error plot (PNG)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNN1s.png)

Do you think you can fix it?

Comment: Try learning rate ``lr=0.1``

Comment: thanks so much! it worked. How did the learning rate affect it?

Answer (score 1):

Due to large learning rate, your model is unable to find minima.

In your code, use adaptive learning rate as:

```
lr = lr - lr/epochs
```

Add this at the last inside your `for` loop.

Also, initialize your learning rate at a smaller value.

Answer (score 1):

Try tuning your model training using different learning rates. `lr=0.2` is too aggressive and causes your model to diverge. For `lr=0.1`, the model looks to be learning OK.